# How to properly display certain variables in React

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get current year displayed in Reactjs but when I run the code it throws the following error below:

> Error: dispatch must be called inside of an event handler or within the function arguments of useAction, useState or useContentProperty at ReconcilerState.enqueueSideEffectIfEnabled

Here is the code:

```
//import goes here

const fetchTimer = async () => {
};     
 
const App = () => {
const [timer, setTimer] = useState(null);
const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();

 setTimer(currentYear);
/*
 useEffect(() => {
    setTimer(currentYear);
  });
*/
    


  return (
    <div>

      <div>Get time and Year:({timer})</div>

    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you do `const [timer, setTimer] = useState(new Date().getFullYear()`? I think that should solve that

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `setState` in the root of the function. That way, it will be executed every render.

If that state is constant, you can use that `currentYear` variable. If it will be changed, you can use `useEffect` with its second array parameter:

```
  const App = () => {
    const [timer, setTimer] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
      const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
      setTimer(currentYear);
    }, []);

    return (
      <div>

        <div>Get time and Year:({timer})</div>

      </div>
  );
};
```

With that second parameter, instead of executing after every render, it will be executed every time the values inside that array changes. If there are no values, it will be executed only at startup: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html